# Remove empty space for the fancy header

Tags: margins, fancyhdr

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\geometry{includeheadfoot,verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=0.7cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
  \renewcommand\footrule{}
  \renewcommand\headrule{
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
      \hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm
      \centering{address address address address\\
        Phone: +7 (000) 000-00-00}
    \end{minipage}
  }

  \lhead{\centering \large{Limited liablity company}\\\huge{``Our superb company''}}
  \rhead{}
  \lfoot{}
  \rfoot{}
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\AtBeginDocument{\vspace*{2\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\begin{center}
  \huge{\textbf{Letter of attourney}}
\end{center}

\bigskip
Moscow, Russia\hfill 08 of October 2018

\bigskip
\bigskip
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

I needed to create a document with a special header on the first page only. Unfortunately, the empty space for the header was preserved on the second page.

How to make the following:

1. Remove the empty space from the 2-nd page.
2. On the 2-nd page make the top margin 1.5cm, and not 1cm as written in the geometry. While keep 1cm margin for the 1-st page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Since you have only 1 page that differs from the rest (the first page), set the header for that page using `\smash` to remove any adjustments introduced automatically by [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
  includeheadfoot,
  tmargin = 1cm,
  bmargin = 0.7cm,
  hmargin = 2cm,
  headheight = 19pt
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[C]{%
    \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} }
      \large Limited liability company \\
      \huge ``Our superb company'' \\[0.5\normalbaselineskip]
      \hline \\[-0.5\normalbaselineskip]
      address address address address \\
      Phone: +7 (000) 000-00-00
    \end{tabular}}
  }
  \renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}% Remove header rule
}

\pagestyle{plain}% Default page style

\AtBeginDocument{\vspace*{\baselineskip}}% For first page only

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\begin{center}
  \huge\bfseries Letter of attourney
\end{center}

\bigskip

Moscow, Russia \hfill 08 of October 2018

\bigskip \bigskip

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

2. Don't set the header as a header at all; rather move it into position if need be.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{
  tmargin = 1.5cm,
  bmargin = 1.5cm,
  hmargin = 2cm
}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\AtBeginDocument{\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}}% For first page only

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} }
  \large Limited liability company \\
  \huge ``Our superb company'' \\[0.2\normalbaselineskip]
  \hline \\[-0.5\normalbaselineskip]
  address address address address \\
  Phone: +7 (000) 000-00-00
\end{tabular}

\begin{center}
  \huge\bfseries Letter of attourney
\end{center}

\bigskip

Moscow, Russia \hfill 08 of October 2018

\bigskip \bigskip

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The top margin on the 2-nd page still seems too big to me. How can it be set to 1.5cm?

Comment: @user4035: Use something like `tmargin=0cm` and adjust the negative `\vspace` to something like `-2\baselineskip`.

Comment: Maybe, try without `includeheadfoot`? But in this case we'll need to increase the size of the header on the 1-st page somehow.

Comment: @user4035: My suggestion pertains to option 2 (my preferred option due to the nature of your question).

Comment: I improved the answer. For the 2-nd case we don't need fancyhdr, I removed `includeheadfoot` and adjusted the heights of skip. Now it looks as I wanted. Thx!